# insecure content from soundcloud embed url = http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ssl, soundcloud

I'm using the auto_html gem to embed soundcloud urls.

In my chrome javascript console I receive the following error:

```
The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from http://w.soundcloud.com/
player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F87676243&show_artwork=true.
```

and this warning.

```
Unsafe access frame with URL https://app.herokuapp.com/ from frame with URL https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F87676243&show_artwork=true. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I have no idea why the top one isn't https?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Chrome – https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17325

And has no practical implications for you, just ignore it until it's fixed. Every embed such as youtube or vimeo has it. Sorry :(

Comment: I get that the second error is a chrome bug but I still get the top one in safari. I think it's either an issue with soundcloud embeds (because youtube embeds aren't secure), or the gem i used for embedding